# Jquery - ERROR 414: Request-URI Too Large

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I've hit the issue where the Request URI is too large. I've looked at various posts on here advising to use post, not get. I've tried that and I still get the same issue.

This is the code I'm currently using:

```
urlData = encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(data))
    $.ajax({
        type: "post", 
        cache: false,
        url: "test.php?urldata=" + urlData,
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data)
        }
    });
```

I've tried changing `$.ajax` to `$.post`, with the same results.

test.php is using `$_REQUEST['varname']` and I've also tried `$_POST['varname']`

How do I send the data from the browser to the back end php page without hitting this limits ? any pointers as to what I'm doing wrong. ?

I don't have access to apache2 to make any changes there.

Thanks

Comment: don't post the data on the url. use the body.

Comment: thanks can you point me in the right direction on how to do this ?

Comment: it really depends on your `data` - https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is pass the large amount of data in the headers of the request instead of as a query string on the URL. You can do this with `jQuery.ajax()` by using the `data` setting. Try:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  cache: false,
  url: "test.php", // remove the concat causing the error
  data: data, // send your data via the data setting
  success: function(response) {
    $.publish('/imports/refresh_row', response);
  }
});
```

Then on the PHP side you will be able to use `$_POST['varname']` to retrieve individual items sent in the `data` object.

Comment: Thanks. I've been looking at this and I don't see any data sent across when this is done. In my test.php script I've added `print_r(compact(array_keys(get_defined_vars())));` but nothing appears for the data I've sent.

Comment: Thanks I realised what I was doing wrong. This helped a lot.